# How to add a scroll bar to a component in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, scrollbar

I'm using a grid system with 3 columns in my SPA. The left and right list contain components that occupy 100 of the viewport height. The middle column contains a long list and would like to add a scrollbar just to the middle component. I've tried to wraw the middle component with several different scrollbar components but nothing works. I end up always with a main page scroll which leaves me only with the list component when scroll further down and left and right component are remaining remain to the top of the page.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try adding `overflow-y: scroll;` on the middle component

```js
const items = [...Array(100)].map((val, i) => `Item ${i}`);

const App = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="left-col">
      Left col
    </div>
    
    <div className="center-col">
      <span>List</span>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, i) => (<li key={`item_${i}`}>{ item }</li>))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div className="right-col">
      Right col
    </div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left-col {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

.center-col {
  flex: 1;
  background: #aaa;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.right-col {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, need to set fixed height to left and right component and overflow:scroll to middle component.