# How to overlay a React component over a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to get my React component to overlay ontop of a Div but I've been having no luck for the past several hours. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656623/position-absolute-scrolling/26089986) StackOverflow example that is exactly what I am looking for but it isn't working. I tried to cut out most of the irrelevant part of my code and I'm using Styled Components:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 24px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  overflow-y: auto;
`;

const Inner = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
`;

const Overlay= styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

function FileSystem() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Inner>
        <Overlay>I want this to not scroll</Overlay>
        <FileList />
      </Inner>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

When this renders, the ***I want this to not scroll*** is overlayed and centered in the parent container. However, once the FileList component get populated and causes the div to overflow, then it stops working and the ***I want this to not scroll*** scrolls with the FileList component. How do I get it to stay at the same location and not scroll with the parent??

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with applying `overflow-y: scroll;` to the div you want to have the scrolling behavior.

Stated another way: Instead of applying CSS to keep the overlay fixed, you apply `overflow-y: scroll;` to the other div (in your case, would be another styled div that holds the contents of ).

Something like:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 24px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  overflow-y: auto;
`;

const Inner = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
`;

const Overlay= styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

//This is the new styled div to contain the area you want to scroll

const ScrollableDiv = styled.div`
overflow-y: scroll;
`;

function FileSystem() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Inner>
        <Overlay>I want this to not scroll</Overlay>
        //This is the new div to add
        <ScrollableDiv> 
        <FileList />
        </ScrollableDiv>
      </Inner>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Note: I didn't test the code above, so it is directional. I am not sure how the `position: absolute;` on the overlay will interact.

The answer on the question below led me to getting mine working.

[How to add a scroll bar to a component in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891589/how-to-add-a-scroll-bar-to-a-component-in-react)